# Inheritance b/w Edges

Tags: inheritance, orientdb, graph-databases

I have a class of edge as selling_link and another class as sold_link while sold_link is having the same attributes as selling_link just one additional attribute is included in sold_link so what do you guys suggest should i inherit selling_link into sold_link?

Answer (score 0):

With [OrientDB](http://www.orientdb.com) You can use inheritance between edge classes, mostly if it's useful to use polymorphism. Example:

```
select from order where in('ordered').city in 'Rome'
```

If you have ordered edge class as base class and other classes that extend it. In this case the query fetches all the incoming edges of classes that are "instanceof ordered".